# mod rewrite regular expressions with a specific length

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

OK. I have this regular expression in my .htaccess file to rewrite / anything alphanumeric to index.php?id=alphanumeric string.

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^([A-Z-a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

the problem i'm having is that when some other variables get added to that string, everything stops working.

For example:

www.someaddress.com/ABCDEFGH works fine.

www.someaddress.com/ABCDEFGH&othervariable=123 fails.

I know my alpha numeric string is always 8 characters. is there a way to make the regular expression only match 8 and leave the rest of the string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick. You want to remove the $ to let it ignore the rest of the variables.

RewriteRule ^([A-Z-a-z0-9]{8}) index.php?id=$1

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{8}) index.php?id=$1
```

Please note the `-` character between `Z` and `a` is not required

Comment: mine was earlier! see the time :)

Comment: i saw you'd updated yours most recently but his was posted just before. i've given you a +1 at least. thanks for your help dude.